# Convert HTML ordered and unordered lists to kramdown

Tags: perl, kramdown

Is it possible to use a Perl script to convert HTML ordered and unordered lists to [*kramdown*](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/), if the file may contain multiple lists of both kinds, as well as other HTML code?

To illustrate the intention, something like the following could work if there is only one ordered list and no other lists:

```
$content =~ s!<\/ol>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<ol>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<\/li>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<li>!1. !gis;
```

Or this could work if there is only one unordered list and no other lists:

```
$content =~ s!<\/ol>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<ol>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<\/li>!!gis;
$content =~ s!<li>!- !gis;
```

Is it possible to find each list in the HTML document, for example, and pass it to a subroutine which would determine the type of list, convert it appropriately and return it?

Comment: Have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use kramdown itself since it can parse HTML and emit a kramdown document.

With the kramdown binary just use `kramdown -i html -o kramdown INPUT.HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Instead, you should use an HTML parser like [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Mojo::DOM;

# Add the appropriate kramdown list marker to a Mojo::DOM node representing a
# single <li>, depending on whether it's in an <ol> or <ul>
sub add_list_marker {
    my ($node, $i) = @_;

    my $marker = $node->parent->tag eq 'ol' ? "$i. " : '- ';
    $node->prepend_content($marker);
}

# Convert a Mojo::DOM node representing an <ol> or <ul> to the corresponding
# kramdown
sub list_to_kramdown {
    my ($node) = @_;

    my $items = $node->children('li')->each(\&add_list_marker);
    my $text = $items->map('text')->join("\n");

    $node->replace("\n$text\n");
}

my $html = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>
};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
$dom->find('ol, ul')->each(\&list_to_kramdown);
print $dom->to_string;

__DATA__
<h1>Leave surrounding HTML</h1>
<div id="including_enclosing_tags">
  <ol>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li><li>baz</li>
    <li>qux</li>
  </ol>
  <ul>
    <li class="fruit">apple</li>
    <li>pear</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>pine
        apple</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Leave surrounding HTML</h1>
<div id="including_enclosing_tags">

1. foo
2. bar
3. baz
4. qux


- apple
- pear
- banana
- pine apple

</div>
```

This is better than a regex because it can easily handle:

- multiple `<li>` elements on the same line
- `<li>` elements that span more than one line
- elements with attributes